# Как пронумеровать блоки в JavaScript и поместить внутрь точку, которая будет на onclick перемещаться?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Нужно чтобы на странице браузера были пронумерованные блоки в виде прямоугольников. Внутри первого блока должен располагаться элемент (в виде точки, картинки, чего угодно), который при нажатии на кнопку "вперёд" будет переходить в соседний блок.

Пока дошел до того что нарисовал следующие друг за другом прямоугольники, но не знаю как пронумеровать и поместить внутрь прямоугольника элемент:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
for (var i = 10; i < 800; i += 50) {
  var a = 0;
  context.strokeRect(i, 10, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<canvas width="900" height="1200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('svs'),
  canvas_two = document.getElementById('svs'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  ctx_Rect = canvas_two.getContext("2d");

for (var i = 10; i < 800; i += 50) {
  var a = 0;
  ctx.strokeRect(i, 10, 50, 50);
  ctx.strokeText(((i - 10) / 50 + 1).toString(), i + 20, 40);

}
x = 10,
  y = 10,
  wid = 20,
  hei = 20;

function drawRect(x, wid, hei, clear) {
  if (clear == true) {
    ctx_Rect.clearRect(x - 49, y + 1, wid + 1, hei + 1);
  }

  ctx_Rect.fillStyle = '#666';
  ctx_Rect.fillRect(x + 2, y, wid, hei);
}

drawRect(x, wid, hei, false);

function myfunction(){
 if (x <= 710) {
    x = x + 50;
    
    clear = true;
    
    drawRect(x, wid, hei, clear);
  }  
}
```

```html
<canvas id="svs" width="900" height="120"></canvas>
<button id="move" onclick="myfunction()">вперед</button>
```